# Exodus and Eternl extensions in chrome and brave are incompatible?

Tags: wallet, eternl

Im developing some dApp with a wallet connector using the extensions in chrome and brave.
Everything was working fine until I installed Exodus extension.
Something in creating a conflict here.

Look pictures attached:

1- This is my wallet connector before enabling Exodus extension:

[image]

2- Now, look the icons when I enable Exodus:

[image]

The Eternl icon disappears and also the functionality of Eternl wallet.
If I press that button it will open the Exodus wallet.

I checked in the windows.cardano object and I also found the problem there:

3- This is before enabling Exodus:

[image]

4- This is with Exodus wallet extension enabled:

[image]

You can see that the Eternl object is overwriting with the same content that the exodus object and only the name eternal is left.

Any idea? It is a bug? From who? Eternl? Exodus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. I would lean toward it being firmly rooted on Exodus, but could be the fault of both Eternl and Exodus. The problem seems to be with variable scope. They both seem to obfuscate their front end code, which ends up making variables like `A = N('icon')`. If those variables are not scoped properly, other things will override them. For example, if both extension make use of A, one of them could have their functionality changed by the other. Theoretically, Exodus could simply grab window.cardano.eternl.icon and set it, but that would seem malicious and really offer no benefit. I would report the bug to both, as I can confirm that what you're seeing is happening to me as well. [image]